# Conditional deserializing a field, based on another field's value

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have this JSON model:

```
{
    state (int),
    result (object)
}
```

The `result` may contain one of these models:

```
public class Person {
    someField;
}

public class Book {
    someOtherFields;
}
```

I mean, I'm looking for a way to do this:

```
if(result.state == 1)
    then deserialize result as a Person
else if(result.state == 2)
    then deserialize result as a Book
else throw exception;
```

I'm not a JAVA or Android guy. This is just a bad situation I got stuck in. Do you have any idea how to do this by using GSON lib in an Android app?

Comment: a custom deseriliazer would do that

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a cutom deserializer

If `Book` and `Person` have a parent class called `Element`, you can create this deserializer (not tested)

```
public class LatLngDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Element> {

    @Override
    public Element deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject jobject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        int state = jobject.get("state").getAsInt();

        if(state == 1)
            return new Person();
        else if (state == 2)
            return new Book();
        else
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

then register it using

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Element.class, new CustomDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

and then parse using

```
Element element= gson.fromJson(jsonInput, Element.class);
```